# System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at LicenseParser.RawDataReader.ParseIT(String LicenseID)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, nullreferenceexception, object-reference

I know this error has been mentioned several times on this site, but i can't figure out what specifically i need to change in order to fix my code. 'LicenseID' is not being recognized when i run the following code...

Main page: default.aspx.vb

```
Public Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Public Shared LicenseID As String

    Public Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        LicenseID = Request.QueryString("LicenseID")
        TextBox4.Text = LicenseID

    End Sub

    Public Sub ParseData_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GetXML.Click
        Dim XML As New GetXML
        Dim ReturnMessage As String = ""

        TextBox1.Text = XML.BuildStatus()
        TextBox2.Text = XML.ReadData(LicenseID)

        Dim RDR As New RawDataReader
    End Sub

End Class
```

Here is the class that is having the issue (RawDataReader). The sub is ParseIT. Does anyone know where i need to move License ID? It does seem to be scoping issue.

```
Public Class RawDataReader
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Public Lic As RawData.License
    Public msg As Object

    Public Sub deserializexml(ByRef Path As String)
        msg = "deserializeComplete"
        Try

            Dim s As New XmlSerializer(GetType(RawData.License))
            Dim fs As New FileStream(Path, FileMode.Open)
            Dim rdr As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(fs)

            Lic = CType(s.Deserialize(rdr), RawData.License)

            fs.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try

    End Sub

    Dim cn As Connection

    Public Sub New()
        cn = New Connection("Operations6")

    End Sub


    Public Sub ParseIT(LicenseID As String)

        Try
            msg = "deserializeComplete"

            For Each itm In Lic.Products

                cn.getScalar(" Exec LicenseUpsert " & _
                    "'" & LicenseID & "', " & _
                    "'" & itm.ProductName & "', " & _
                   "'" & itm.ExpiresOn & "'")


                If Not Lic.Products(0) Is Nothing Then
                    With Lic.Products(0)

                    End With
                End If
            Next

        Catch ex As Exception
            msg = ex.ToString()
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)